# Цепочка конструкторов в классе-наследнике

Tags: c#

C# VisStd 13 Express, Windows 8.1
Каким образом построить цепочку конструкторов, чтобы в конструкторе производного класса с параметрами сначала выполнялся его конструктор по умолчанию?

Вот мой код:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace TestForClass
{
    public class Parent
    {
        public int p1, p2;
        public Parent()
        {
            p1 = p2 = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("p1 = {0} p2 = {1}", p1, p2);
        }
//-----------------------------------------------------------
        public Parent(int k)
        {
            p1 = k;
            p2 = k + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("p1 = {0} p2 = {1}", p1, p2);
        }
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------
    public class Daughter: Parent
    {
        public int d, z;
        public Daughter():base()
        {
            d = 17;
        }
        public Daughter(int z, int k):base(k)
        {
            this.z = z;
            Console.WriteLine("p1 = {0} p2 = {1} d = {2}, z = {3}", p1, p2, d, z);
        }
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------     class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parent p = new Parent();
            Parent pP = new Parent(4);
            Daughter d = new Daughter();
            Daughter dP = new Daughter(8, 6);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: какой вывод в итоге ожидается?

Comment: Вместо base() вызывайте this()

Comment: тогда неправильные значеня у переменных Р1 и Р2

Comment: вывод сейчас: p1 = 6 p2 = 7 d = 0, z = 8 ;
желательный: p1 = 6 p2 = 7 d = 17, z = 8

Comment: перенесите `d = 17;` в `Daughter(int z, int k)`. Конструктор по умолчанию сделайте пустым. Вместо `base()` вызывайте `this(0, 0)`. так: `public Daughter() : this(0, 0)`